# asp.net hidden field value not getting on form load event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

on body load i am calling this function

```
<body  onload="lotclick('1');">
```

in this function i am assigning value to hidden field

```
function lotclick(lotid) 
{
    var dt = new Date();

    document.getElementById("lblindTime").value = dt.toString();
```

and in code behind file on form load event i am trying to get value of that hidden field.but i am unable to get that value.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string sfsf = lblindTime.Value.ToString();
    }
```

but i am not getting any value. but on button click i am getting value. 
what will be the issue.??

Comment: In your case Page_Load gets executed first! So at this point there is no value. Then, onload gets executed and sets the value. So it makes sense that only on button-click you should have value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i am not getting any value. but on button click i am getting value.

Are you expecting the value to be there the *first* time you load the page?  Because that's not possible.  When you click the button, you post back to the server and that post-back includes the values which were set client-side.  Which is why your button click is "working."

However, when you first load the page, your server-side code can't see client-side values which *haven't been calculated yet*.  The order of operations in your case is roughly:

1. User requests page
2. `Page_Load` executes
3. Page is loaded in browser
4. JavaScript executes
5. Form field is updated
6. User clicks button
7. Form fields are sent to the server
8. `Page_Load` executes
9. Click handler executes
10. and so on...

Step 2 can't use a value that isn't going to be calculated until step 4.  ASP .NET doesn't support prescience (yet).

Answer (score 2):

you can't get it that way as the `Page_Load` is executed on server side and get executed waaay before `onload` get executed on client side